# Programmatically detect if a MessageBox is open in Windows CE

Tags: c++, windows-ce, messagebox

I would like to know if it is possible to detect (programmatically) if a Message Box is open in c++, I have an application running in Windows CE and I call a bunch of Message Boxes from various locations when things go wrong, is there a way to detect that one of these boxes have indeed poped up?

I call a Message Box as follows:

```
::MessageBox (NULL,TEXT("Could not close COM2"),TEXT("Feedback"),MB_OK);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to your question is to use [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453070.aspx) or [EnumWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa453051.aspx).

The better answer is to ask why you want to do this. Rather than popping up error boxes in various places all over your code, have functions return an error code and then a more centralized error handling structure should translate those errors in to a message for the user.